# How to create a shopping report using information from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary, report

like this

Shopping report

Name1

Thing1 number1 cost1

Thing11 number11 cost11
the amount to be paid

Name2

Thing2 number2 cost2

Thing22 number22 cost22

the amount to be paid

text file

Petrov pen 10 151000

Borzov paper 20 20000

Butar case-boks 5 5000

Semerik pen2 500 250000

Petrov pen(oil) 100 10000

Borzov paper 40 40000

Butar book 5 15000

Semerik hat 500 250000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Stack overflow\\textfile.txt"
newpath = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Stack overflow\\textfileout.txt"
text = open(path, "r")
textinfo = text.readlines()
dictofinfo = {}
for line in textinfo:
  line = line.strip()
  lineaslist = line.split(" ")
  name = lineaslist[0]
  if not(name in dictofinfo.keys()):
    dictofinfo[lineaslist[0]] = [lineaslist[1:]]
  else:
    dictofinfo[lineaslist[0]].append(lineaslist[1:])
text.close()

out = open(newpath, "w")
for entry in dictofinfo:
  totaltobepayed = 0
  out.write(entry + "\n")
  for seperateentry in dictofinfo[entry]:
    totaltobepayed += int(seperateentry[2])
    out.write(" ".join(seperateentry) + "\n")
  out.write(str(totaltobepayed) + "\n")
out.close()
```

Replace the path variable with the path to your text file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but now need to solve another problem. How to output it in a text document using the key and the value of the dictionary and calculating the cost to be paid?